# How can I get the form select value to show two things in the table being inserted?

Tags: php, forms, pdo

I have 2 tables. products (id, name, description, category id, category name) and categories (id, name, description). I created a form which uses options from categories. When form submitted the category id is inserted to products which is nice, but I would like the category id and category name to be inserted into products. How can I do that? My head is spinning.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO products SET name=:name, description=:description, 
category_name=:category_name, category_id=:category_id, image=:image, created=:created";

<?php
$query = "SELECT id, name FROM categories ORDER BY name";
$stmt = $con->prepare( $query );
$stmt->execute();

echo "<select class='form-control' name='category_id'>";
echo "<option>Select category...</option>";

while ($row_group = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
extract($row_group);

echo "<option value='{$id}'>{$name}</option>";
}

echo "</select>";
?>
```

Comment: Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite a textbook with a bespoke tutorial. Time to follow a published academic textbook on information modelling, the relational model & DB design. (Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not such textbooks.) (Nor are wiki articles or web posts.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly that's not a good approach in terms of redundancy. The whole point of good database design (normalization) is to eliminate repeating groups and partial dependencies on non keyed attributes.

A better table structure is:

products (id, name, description, category id)
categories (id, name, description)

INSERT the category_id as needed into the Product and then when you need the Product Name / Descripton AND Category name/Description you query it with a JOIN

```
$sql = "SELECT p.*, c.name cname, c.description cdesc FROM products p INNER JOIN categories c ON (c.id = p.category_id) WHERE p.name=:product_name";

$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute( [ ':product_name' => 'toy car' ] );

foreach($stmt as $row) {
    echo $row['name']; //product name
    echo $row['cname']; //category name column aliased as cname
    echo $row['cdesc']; //category description aliased
}
```